# For loop nested in while loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, while-loop

I have written a while loop in Matlab that is supposed to determine the value of the parameter "n" for "a" to exceed the value 300. I know "n" should be 17, but I'm getting a value of 4 instead. Does anyone see the problem?

The code is as follows:

```
a = 10;
k = 0.5;
n = 2;
while a < 300
    for m = 1:5
        a = a + (a*k) + n;
    end
    n = n + 1;
end
```

Edit:
I realized that I didn't reinitialize my "a" variable, thanks to Barmar's comment. Although the code might not look very efficient, this is what works for me:

```
a = 10;
k = 0.5;
n = 2;
while a < 300
    a = 10;
    for m = 1:5
        a = a + (a*k) + n;
    end
    if a >= 300
        break
    end
    n = n + 1;
end
```

Comment: Don't you need to reinitialize `a` when you try different values of `n`?

Comment: Perhaps that formula isn't doing what you think it's doing.  You multiply `a` by 1.5 and add 2.  You do this 5 times, then increase `n` to 3.  At that point, `a` is already larger than 100.  I don't think `n` is going to make it all the way to 17.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I figured out how to fix my code.

Answer (score 0):

If your formula is correct then 4 is the answer you should expect. The first for loop run turns a into the respsective values:

```
17, 27, 42, 65, 99
```

Which then turns n to 3. The next run turns a into:

```
151, 229, 346, 522, 786
```

Notice that a is now > 300 but we have to increment n one more time. Thus n = 4.